# how to hot deploy code in apache tomcat 8 in myeclipse 2014

Tags: maven, jsf-2.2, tomcat8, myeclipse

me using tomcat 8, java 7 myeclipse 2014 and project nature is dynamic webmodule 3.1 with maven support

in my web.xml im using

javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE Development

javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD 1

and my autodeploymnet option is on

still im unable to get results like im changing my xhtml page or method body its not deployed auto. everytime i need to restart my server.

here is my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Setting up application context used for spring configuration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- welcome file for Application -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>workflow</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name> 
    <param-value>1</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Make sure you're running in debug mode and perhaps try changing the refresh period to 0. Also posting the full web.xml might enable others to spot any problems.

Comment: thnx workspace was corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything was fine except the corrupted workspace, i changed to new workspace and everything works fine.